# jQuery - How to add id="menu1" in the first ul

Tags: jquery

How to use jquery to add some element like id="menu1" in the first ul?

```
<ul /*Add to Here*/ >
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$('ul:first').attr('id', 'menu1');
```

Or:

```
$('ul').eq(0).attr('id', 'menu1');
```

Or:

```
$('ul').first().attr('id', 'menu1');
```

And there are probably half a dozen other good solutions.

Have a look at jQuery's documentation:

- [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)
- [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)
- [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/)
- [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

PS: If you want to manipulate the `class` attribute, don't use `.attr()`. Use [`.addClass()` and its siblings](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/) instead.

Comment: @user964351: if this answered your question, you should mark it as the accepted answer (see [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)).

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('ul:first').attr('id', 'menu1');

});
```